# On bootstrap modal

Tags: angular6, bootstrap-modal

Bootstrap modal is not working in any of the browsers. There is neither error in code nor any errors triggered in console in the browser. Could not find the problem. At first I thought of browser compatibility. Later I also changed the setting in chrome on pop ups. Everything is fine still modal doesn't work.
The code goes like this. Even I checked with  tags. Still the error is not resolved. I have tried many options to make it work, but failed. Please help me

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Artificial Intelligence</button>

      <div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            About AI
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: did you include bootstrap's js? maybe show us the entire html file

Answer (score 0):

Are you included bootstrap js file in your code ? please check without valid bootstrap js it will not work